# I am not able to update state using set method react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing GET api call to receive data for infinite scrolling. So every time the scrollbar reaches to particular position, it does a GET call to fetch more data. So I need to update the offset every time here, but `setOffset(prevOffset => prevOffset + 1)` is not working, and remaining to initial value(0) for next calls. However, I am able to merge new data with the existing one using `setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, ...data])`, New data means its fetching the same data here as offset is not getting updated.

I want to update offset value with each api call.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const API_KEY = '***';
  const API_BASE_URL = 'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search';
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight)
    {
      return;
    }
    fetchData();
  }

  const createURL = () => {
    const url = new URL(API_BASE_URL);
    url.searchParams.set('q', 'hello');
    url.searchParams.set('api_key', API_KEY);
    console.log('lets print offset', offset);
    url.searchParams.set('offset', offset);
    return url;
  }

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(createURL());
      const { data, pagination } = await response.json();
      console.log('lets print', pagination);
      setImages(prevImages => [...prevImages, ...data]);
      setOffset(prevOffset => prevOffset + 1);
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Testimonials</h1>
      <div className="testimonialContainer">
        {images.map((image,idx) => {
          return (
            <p key={idx} className="testimonial">{image.title}</p>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closure problem (stale closure). There is a simple trick with `useRef` you can use.

```
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
const offsetRef = useRef();
offsetRef.current = offset;
...
const createURL = () => {
   ...
   url.searchParams.set('offset', offsetRef.current);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and its working. But can you please explain the problem here ? I am not able to understand the exact issue here with stale closure.

Comment: When the component renders for first time, createURL knows about offset as 0. useEffect knows about that createURL. In second render offset is 1, it defines new createURL function that knows offset = 1. But the useEffect still refers to the old createUrl that knows offset as 0. In short - closure captures outdated variables. More about it you can find online https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the clear understanding of stale closure.